# Change filename when downloading data from datatable R

Tags: r, datatable

I'm using `datatable` inside an R shiny web app.

How can I change the file name that is gonna be created when donwloading a datatable object?

For example:

```
  datatable(
      iris2,
      extensions = 'Buttons', options = list(
        dom = 'Bfrtip',
        buttons = 
          list('copy', 'print', list(
            extend = 'collection',
            buttons = c('csv', 'excel', 'pdf'),
            text = 'Download'
          ))

      )
    )
```

I want the file donwloaded to be named by default "iris.xlsx" or "iris.csv" . Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because of `extend = "collection"`, you need to include the `filename` argument through a *nested* `list` inside the `button = list(...)`

```
library(DT)
datatable(
      iris,
      extensions = 'Buttons', options = list(
        dom = 'Bfrtip',
        buttons =
          list('copy', 'print', list(
            extend = 'collection',
            buttons = list(
                list(extend = 'csv', filename = "iris"),
                list(extend = 'excel', filename = "iris"),
                list(extend = 'pdf', filename = "iris")),
            text = 'Download'
          ))
      )
    )
```

---

### Without a `collection` of buttons

If you don't want a `collection` of sub-buttons and instead wanted to specify a filename for a single file type (let's say a CSV file), you can do this

```r
library(DT)
datatable(
    iris,
    extensions = 'Buttons', options = list(
        dom = 'Bfrtip',
        buttons =
            list('copy', 'print', list(
                extend = 'csv',
                title = "interesting_file"))))
```

THe key is to use `extend = "csv"` to specify the file type and then use `title` for the filename, all inside a `list`.

Comment: How would this go if `extend = 'collection'` wasn't there?

Comment: @EricKrantz Please see my edit.